# keeping safe assets folder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi i have this assets folder which has the following folder inside of css, images, uploads, and js folder i put the assets folder outside application. Im wondering that how could i keep it safe so that when users tried to type in the url like for example `http:/test.com/assets` it will redirect to application folder or somewhat it will says page not found. Cause ive noticed that when i type in the url `http://test.com/assets` it will go to the assets folder and which is vulnerable and people could see all the folders in the assets folder. can someone help me figued this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to secure you folder then do one this create `html` file like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and save it as `index.html` and put it on your `assets folder` whenever some try to access your url `http://test.com/assets` then this index file will execute and its shows `Directory access is forbidden.`